# Magento, 1 db field not saved

Tags: magento, model, save

I have a problem with one field of the DB. With this code:

```
$expireMonth = Mage::getStoreConfig('points_options/config_points/expiration_period', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());

if (!is_null($expireMonth) && ($expireMonth > 0)) {
    $expireDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+" . $expireMonth . " month"));
} else {
    $expireDate = NULL;
}

//die($expireDate);
//store in points history table
$this->_pointsModel->setCustomerId($this->_customer->getId())
                   ->setOrdersId('welcome')
                   ->setPointsPending($pointsForNewCustomer)
                   ->setPointsComment(Mage::helper('points')->__('welcome points'))
                   ->setDateAdded(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                   ->setPointsStatus(2)//confirmed
                   ->setPointsType('WE')
                   ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                   ->setExpireDate($expireDate)
                   ->save();
```

Every field is saved in the table, except for `expire_date`. If I uncomment the `die($expireData)`, I see the correct value, something like 2012-01-13 13:21:12. The field is defined as:

```
`expire_date` datetime NULL
```

Any thoughts?

**edit:** The solution is:

```
$expireDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+" . $expireMonth . " months"));
```

Check out the "s" in my strtotime expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know many attributes allow for some sort of formatting before writing and after reading. Have you tried setting the value as a unix timestamp instead?

Comment: OMG!!! it turns out that there was missing a "s" in my strtotime expression, it has to be "months", not "month".  
You're answer isn't really the solution, but you made me think abouot it and it helped me to find it, so, here are some points ;)
thanx clockworkgeek, see you around